# Make index.html show instead of Default.aspx?

Tags: asp.net

We are working on an aspx site that we would like to not show users until we are ready to launch. The Default.aspx seems to have more "power" over my index.html file. All I would like to do is show the index.html by default and when working on the site, we can navigate to Default.aspx and work from there.

Comment: Have you tried making index.html top of the list of the Default pages for the application?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is an IIS setting.

In IIS 7 or above, use the Default Document tool. In IIS 6 or below, use the "Default Documents" tab.

Comment: Thanks!, can't accept this as correct for another 9 minutes though.

Answer (score 2):

in the "Default Document" settings of your IIS you simply have to change the order of the "Default DOcuments" and make sure that index.html is above Default.aspx.

IIS6: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx?mfr=true

IIS7: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753615(WS.10).aspx