# Default.aspx vs. Index.aspx

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I've been using `Index.aspx` as the 'home' file of my web applications directories for the past 5 years, but have only just recently started using Visual Studio for debugging sites.

The built in web server for Visual Studio has `Default.aspx` as the 'home' file.

When I click on a link such as `/News?id=5`, its not picking up on the `Index.aspx` file, and instead showing a directory listing.

This causes an issue because I'm sometimes passing querystring, which is then lost when going to the directory listing.

Therefore, should I cave in and do what Microsoft tells me, and use `Default.aspx`?

Is this what all other ASP.NET web developers do?

Comment: As much as it's always pained me, here we've always used Default.aspx purely because it's the microsoft 'way'

Comment: Cheers @Jroc, I hate how Microsoft throw their weight about with stuff like this!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can set this up in the web.config file.

[CORRECTION]: What I was thinking of is actually the  section, which allows to setup 404 pages. You may use that to redirect to Index, but it might not be "good practice".

Hah, amazingly enough, somebody already asked almost the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398565/change-default-default-aspx-to-index-aspx-on-visual-studio-2010), and even another closely related [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030882/make-index-html-show-instead-of-default-aspx), that you probably may use to solve your issue.

You can also write an XML SiteMap file to setup Index.aspx as your toplevel page.

As per convention, as stated in my comment, ASPX.NET convention is to name the pages by the name of their controller's action method, such as Index.aspx, however all examples in the MS70-515 book are based on Default.aspx. My personal opinion therefore would be to use Default.aspx.

Comment: Ha that was me. I didn't find a way of changing it in the end. Changing in the web.config wouldn't work as the web.config isn't read when something like `/News` is requested. The system doesn't recognise this anymore as an ASP.NET file as it does a Jpeg.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm having a look into the MS70-515 book I happen to have on my desktop and tell you if I find stuff :D

Comment: ASPX.Net convention for naming views is to use "the action method in the controller, such as Index.aspx". Could that help somehow? That question actually tickles my brain ;)

Comment: Hmmm not really to be honest! :/

Comment: CustomErrors wouldn't be read, and I don't think this would be classed as a 404 error. To be honest I'm more interested in knowing what is the standard convention, and whether I should just start adopting `Default.aspx` in my future applications

Comment: @Curt let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2608/discussion-between-kheldar-and-curt)